# Usage: "Error of Fact"

Tags: contract-law

If a contractor asserts a series of false statement in a record, whether it is mistaken or intentional, is it incorrect to label the group of false statements "Error(s) of fact"?

Upon looking up an example:

"An [error of fact](https://www.ridoutbarron.com/blog/2016/07/an-error-of-law-versus-an-error-of-fact.shtml) means that you think the **judge** had the wrong facts or interpreted them incorrectly."

I realize that this phrase is normally applied to judge and seeking a phrase to apply to coin the contractor's assertions in a document that would be read by judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "misstatements of fact" would be far more conventional. When a statement is not true, it is a "misstatement", and that term does not imply any particular degree of intent. It is not synonymous with a "lie" or a "fraudulent statement".